# Ruby how to change array to array of string and vice versa

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

How to change something like this

```
array = ["a, b, c, d"]
```

to

```
array = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
```

and vice versa

Comment: What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? Please, provide a [mre].

Comment: @JörgWMittag I've tried with `split` but this is just a sample of solution. I've to change array in to the array of string in my specs. With `first.split(', ')` it shows me an error `NoMethodError:
       undefined method split' for Mon, 17 Jun 2019 16:14:56 CEST +02:00:Time`

Comment: That error message *cannot possibly* be generated from the data in the question.

Comment: You have a date/datetime or similar object, not a string.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you aren't understanding that you aren't working with a string value to begin with. Perhaps you can avoid providing a "sample of solution" (which clearly isn't such) and provide a more detailed and accurate explanation of the problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`String#split`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-split) and [`Array#join`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.4/Array.html#method-i-join):

```
["a, b, c, d"].first.split(', ')
# => ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
[["a", "b", "c", "d"].join(', ')]
# => ["a, b, c, d"]
```

Comment: Is there any other way to do so? I've tried it already and it shows me an error in my specs `NoMethodError:
       undefined method split' for Mon, 17 Jun 2019 16:14:56 CEST +02:00:Time`

Comment: If that is the case, then the example in your question is not representative of your actual problem. Please, read up on how to construct a [mre]. The answer posted here, *exactly* solves the problem you posted in the question. If this answer doesn't solve your actual problem, then there is a problem with your question, not with this answer.